# Prevent C# "with expressions" bypassing constructor validation

Tags: c#

I was disappointed to discover that C#'s "with expressions" allow the caller to bypass constructor validations on the record.

Consider:

```
record AscendingPair { 
    public AscendingPair(int small, int large)
    {
        if (small >= large) throw new ArgumentException("");
        (Small, Large) = (small, large);
    }
    public int Small { get; init; }
    public int Large { get; init; }
}

[Test]
public void Can_create_an_invalid_pair() {
    var valid = new AscendingPair(1, 2);
    var invalid = valid with { Small = 3 }; // This does not throw :(
}
```

Is there a smart workaround that would allow use of `with`, but still enforce the validation?

Comment: It's not `with` fault, but the syntax of `init` properties. `new AscendingPair(1, 2) { Small = 5 }` also works.

Comment: Looks like C#-9.0 `record`-types assume a model where data-fields are mutually independent.  Presumably if you want several fields to be related, you'd want to wrap them up as a child-object.

Comment: Syntactic salt.

Answer (score 29):

The `with` expression is lowered into something like this (check this on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io)):

```
var temp = valid.<Clone>$(); // you can't actually access this from C#
temp.Small = 3;
var invalid = temp;
```

This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#with-expression):

> First, receiver's "clone" method (specified above) is invoked and its result is converted to the receiver's type. Then, each member_initializer is processed the same way as an assignment to a field or property access of the result of the conversion. Assignments are processed in lexical order.

Notes:

- `valid.<Clone$>()` just calls the copy constructor of the record (`new AscendingPair(valid)`).
- It is possible to set `temp.Small` here because you are doing it in the member initialiser list, which is one of the places where you can set init-only properties.

Now it should be clear how exactly the `with` expression bypasses the check in your constructor.

One way to solve this is to move the check to the `init` accessors:

```
record AscendingPair { 
    public AscendingPair(int small, int large)
    {
        if (small >= large) throw new ArgumentException("");
        (Small, Large) = (small, large);
    }
    private int small;
    private int large;
    public int Small { 
        get => small;
        init {
            if (value >= large) {
                throw new ArgumentException("");
            }
            small = value;
        }
    }
    public int Large { 
        get => large;
        init {
            if (small >= value) {
                throw new ArgumentException("");
            }
            large = value;
        }
    }
}
```

There is an important caveat to this fix though: **the order of the assignments in the `with` expression now matters.** This is a natural consequence of how the `with` expression is lowered, with each assignment being "processed in lexical order". For example:

```
var valid = new AscendingPair(1, 2);
var invalid = valid with { Large = 4, Small = 3 };
```

is fine, but,

```
var valid = new AscendingPair(1, 2);
var invalid = valid with { Small = 3, Large = 4 };
```

throws an exception.

We can't really do anything about this though, because to solve this problem, we would need to move the check to *after* all the assignments of the `with` expression have completed, but as far as I know, we can't really know when that is inside the record. The lowered code does not call an extra method or anything like that at the end of the series of assignments.

Comment: Looks like they'd have to define a new `class` that does support having `int .Small` and `int .Large` in their relationship, then have the `record` wrap instances of that class.  Presumably the record could still define `get`-helpers to make it easier to work with the wrapped-object, though someone mutating it would have to declare a `new`-instance if they want to modify `int .Small` or/and `int .Large`.  Which I guess makes sense -- as it doesn't make sense to independently mutate `.Small` and `.Large`, if they're logically tied together.